# Redux error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a problem. I try to create basic structure of my future project, but when I
start my project on localhost I have an error: "Expected the reducer to be a function"

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.js';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App /> 
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

index.js in reducers folder:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({});

export default rootReducer;
```

store.js:

```
import { createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
const composeEnhancers =
  process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
  typeof window === 'object' &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({}) : compose;
/* eslint-enable */

const configureStore = preloadedStore => (
    createStore(
        rootReducer,
        preloadedStore,
        composeEnhancers,
    )
);


const store = configureStore({});

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `rootReducer` does not contain any valid reducer. 
`combineReducers` take an object in the following form:

`combineReducers({ [reducerKey]: reducerFunction  });`

Which in your case is just an empty object.